# How to perform t-tests for each level of a factor with tapply

Tags: r, tapply

My data and code are like this:

```
my_vector <- rnorm(150)
my_factor1 <- gl(3,50)
my_factor2 <- gl(2,75)

tapply(my_vector, my_factor1, function(x)
  t.test(my_vector~my_factor2, paired=T))
```

I want to do a separate t-test for each level of my_factor1, to test my_vector for both levels of my_factor2.

However, with my code the t-test is not splitting the levels of my_factor1, and the results are equal for each level because my_vector is entirely included in each t.test.

This is the output of my code:

```
$`1`

Paired t-test

data:  my_vector by my_factor2
t = 0.2448, df = 74, p-value = 0.8073
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.2866512  0.3669667
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
         0.04015775 


$`2`

Paired t-test

data:  my_vector by my_factor2
t = 0.2448, df = 74, p-value = 0.8073
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.2866512  0.3669667
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
         0.04015775 


$`3`

Paired t-test

data:  my_vector by my_factor2
t = 0.2448, df = 74, p-value = 0.8073
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.2866512  0.3669667
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
         0.04015775
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: you said `function(x)` but where is x in the formula? and also what is `~` in the function?

Comment: `lapply(X = split(my_vector, my_factor1), FUN = function(z) {lapply(X = split(my_vector, my_factor2), FUN  = function(y, z, ...) t.test(y, z), z, paired = T)})` This does what you want in a generic way and can deal with `1:n` factors in factor vector, but it does not use `tapply`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is slightly problematic, since if you set:

```
df <- data.frame(my_vector = rnorm(150),
                 my_factor1 = gl(3,50),
                 my_factor2 = gl(2,75)
                )
```

You will have only one unique value for `my_factor2` when `my_factor1` = 1 or 3 because of how your repetitions overlap.  See `?gl`. So do:

```
df <- data.frame(my_vector = rnorm(150),
                 my_factor1 = gl(3,1,150),
                 my_factor2 = gl(2,1,150)
                )
with(df,
       by(df, my_factor1,
          function(x) t.test(my_vector ~ my_factor2, data=x)
       )
     )
```

Which appears to produce your desired output.

As a side note-- consider correction for multiple comparisons:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16779/when-is-multiple-comparison-correction-necessary

Comment: Hi C8H10N4O2, Great answer, how could I do this with multiple columns?