# R: different errors from using apply()

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I've been trying to debug this for the past 2 days, applying all the possible fixes I found here on Stack Overflow, but I'm still getting various errors and I don't know what I can do anymore.

**dat** is a data frame with 3051 rows and 38 columns, taken from the golub dataset in the multtest library . 
sample of dat:

```
> dat[1:5, 1:5]
     V1       V2       V3       V4       V5
g1 -1.45769 -1.39420 -1.42779 -1.40715 -1.42668
g2 -0.75161 -1.26278 -0.09052 -0.99596 -1.24245
g3  0.45695 -0.09654  0.90325 -0.07194  0.03232
g4  3.13533  0.21415  2.08754  2.23467  0.93811
g5  2.76569 -1.27045  1.60433  1.53182  1.63728
```

I have this function defined:

```
> wilcox.func <- function(x, s1, s2) {
+ x1 <- x[s1]
+ x2 <- x[s2]
+ x1 <- as.numeric(x1)
+ x2 <- as.numeric(x2)
+ w.out <- wilcox.test(x1, x2, exact=F, alternative="two.sided", correct=T)
+ out <- as.numeric(w.out$statistic)
+ return(out) }
```

and I try to apply it with:

```
> apply(dat, 1, wilcox.func, s1=c(1:27), s2=c(28:38))
```

where I want to run the wilcox.test() function with the first 27 columns as x and the remaining columns as y (based off golub.cl). However, I get this error:

> ```
> Error in wilcox.test(x1, x2, exact = F, alternative = "two.sided", correct = T) : 
>   unused arguments (exact = F, alternative = "two.sided", correct = T)
> ```

Removing *exact = F, alternative = "two.sided", correct = T* gives me a new error **Error in x[s1] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts**.

Funnily enough at some point I also got the error **Error in x[s1, ] : incorrect number of dimensions** running the same line of code (with the "unused arguments" *not* removed from wilcox.test), but that was 2 days ago and I haven't been able to reproduce it again.

I've also tried lapply() and mapply(), but I get the same unused arguments error.

What I'm trying to achieve: the wilcox.test(), if I understand the problem correctly, should be applied to each row where the x vector is composed of columns 1 to 28 and the y vector columns 29 to 38.

I apologize if this is a stupid simple issue I'm missing. I just don't know what it is :(

Edit: this works now (as well as Parfait's code) after restarting R... sorry, that should've probably been something I tried first before posting this...

Comment: Please `dput()` your data. Hover your pointer over the `r` tag for more info.

Comment: @Hack-R I'm sorry, it's my first time posting about R. How do I `dput` my data? Do you mean I should have 
   `library(multtest)`
   `dput(data(golub))`

in my post?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you're trying to do. Do you mean a separate test for every combination of columns i.e. 28x9 = 252 tests?

Comment: @Joe It would be 3051 wilcox.test() I think (for the 3051 rows), where x (x1) is composed of cols 1-27 and y (x2) is cols 28-38.

Comment: OK I think I understand. This question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30332752/4477364 asks something similar, have you seen it?

Comment: @Joe, I haven't thank you! I'm having trouble figuring out how to apply it to my situation though. I'll keep working at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `sapply()` or `vapply()` (to predefine output type) iterating across row numbers since you need to slice by column ranges for each row. Below uses sample data but adjust to full `.dat`:

```
# READ IN SAMPLE dat
data ='
V0       V1       V2       V3       V4       V5
g1 -1.45769 -1.39420 -1.42779 -1.40715 -1.42668
g2 -0.75161 -1.26278 -0.09052 -0.99596 -1.24245
g3  0.45695 -0.09654  0.90325 -0.07194  0.03232
g4  3.13533  0.21415  2.08754  2.23467  0.93811
g5  2.76569 -1.27045  1.60433  1.53182  1.63728'

dat <- read.table(text=data, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# ADJUSTED FUNCTION
wilcox.func <- function(s1, s2) {
 x1 <- as.numeric(s1)
 x2 <- as.numeric(s2)

 w.out <- wilcox.test(x1, x2, exact=F, alternative="two.sided", correct=T)
 out <- as.numeric(w.out$statistic)
 return(out) 
}

output <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(dat)), function(i)
    wilcox.func(dat[i, c(2:4)], dat[i, c(5:6)]))    
output
# [1] 2 4 4 3 3

output <- vapply(seq_len(nrow(dat)), function(i)
    wilcox.func(dat[i, c(2:4)], dat[i, c(5:6)]), 
    numeric(1))    
output
# [1] 2 4 4 3 3
```

Comment: Thank you @Parfait, but sadly I'm still getting the same unused arguments error for wilcox.test() :(

Comment: How is that possible? This uses your sample data and exact args in `wilcox.test`. Please check how you are incorporating in actual code. Did you run this solution (w/ sample data included) and received error?

Comment: I used the full data set `dat <- read.table(text=data(golub), header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` rather than the sample subset... would that make a difference? I'm going to try restarting my R session and re-running the code